# Realm query returning wrong result sporadically

Tags: android, realm

I have been noticing that when I have updated an object recently of a certain class and I try to fetch a list of those objects, the most recently updated object is returned with wrong values.

It is not happening every time but it happens every once in a while.

The data gets correctly inserted in the RealmDB.

I am using the following code snippet to fetch from realm.

```
public static <T extends RealmModel> ArrayList<T> fetchAllForKey(Class<T> clazz, String key, boolean value) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(new RealmConfiguration.Builder().build());    
    RealmQuery query = realm.where(clazz);
    query.equalTo(key, value);
    RealmResults<T> results = query.findAll();
    ArrayList<T> list = realm.copyFromRealm(realmResults);
    realm.close;
    return list;
}
```

I have 5 Objects in the RealmDB and when I fetch using the above function I get a list of size 5 but sometimes it returns a list of 4 size even when I have the data in DB and on the subsequent fetch it returns list of size 5.

I am trying to figure out why realm is returning wrong values and a way to mitigate this.

Comment: I assume it has to do with the fact that you are copying from a non-looper background thread, possibly with unclosed local Realm instance somewhere, instead of relying on RealmChangeListener.

Comment: I was also facing the same issue.. It happened because of unclosed realm instance,